# NodePort is not working on minikube on virtual box

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am learning Kubernetes and have a simple deployment and a nodePort service. I am not able to access my deployment using nodePort. I tried `hyperkit`, `docker` and `virtualbox` .

Context

1. My java application is running on `8080` port ( tomcat server )
2. My service port is `8080`.
3. My nodePort is `32000`.

**Here is the service file**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: file-process-service
  labels:
    app: file-process-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080 ---------> Service 
      targetPort: 8080 ----> Tomcat Port
      nodePort: 32000  ----> NodePort 
      protocol: TCP

  selector:
    app: file-process-app
```

Minukube URl is

```
minikube service file-process-service --url

>> http://192.168.59.100:32000
```

Now, when I am trying to access it via postman, I am getting connection refused. Can any one help me where I am doing it wrong or how can I debug it further?

[image]

Thanks DavidMaze - I am attaching the end points. It is None for my service

[image]

Comment: Is the Service correctly binding to the Pods?  (If you `kubectl describe service file-process-service`, what does it say for `Endpoints:`?)  Is the application in fact accessible on the port you say it is (is it listening on 0.0.0.0:8080; can you connect to it via `docker run`)?

Comment: @DavidMaze: I executed the above command and the endpoint is None. Why the endpoint is none. 
Meanwhile let me try running it with docker run

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze : Thanks it got resolved. I mentioned the wrong selector in the service. Hene the endpoints were not created.

Comment: I have the same issue, was hoping to find a solution. I am not using the wrong selector in the service though. Has anyone resolved this issue yet?

Answer (score 0):

It was hinted by @DavidMaze - I found the service is created however end points were not created. I further debug the issue and found that in the service I have mentioned the wrong pods selectors, hence no ep was created.